# MathOverflow answers and peer review

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, the asker does not have sufficient background to verify an answer.  How should one handle such cases?

Some of the signals on whether to accept such an answer are whether it 'looks' good, the reputation of the answerer (in the relevant subject area), upvotes, and that relevant comments are addressed.  However, it is common for upvoters not to really verify the answer either.

I suggest that (despite the policy against 'me too' comments) it is ok for users to comment that they verified the argument, and that it is also ok for the asker to politely ask for such a comment.  We may want to have some form of 'reviewed by' tag to separate these from regular comments.  Also, none of this is meant to detract from that MathOverflow answerers are usually well-meaning persons who prize accuracy.  For both the answerer and the community, having a confirmation that one did not make a mistake can be valuable.

Comment: The up/down votes already let you say what you think of an answer. Personally, I don't see why it's a big deal if an answer gets accepted.

Comment: @SamHopkins I don't think it is simply about accepting or not an answer, but about having confidence in the answer's accuracy.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I see. Well, I think that "I checked this argument and it make sense"-type comments under answers are fine, in the right circumstances (e.g. when the argument is long, involved, or surprising), but I don't think we need a whole separate system for them.

Comment: I've even seen comments to the effect of "wow, this is a genuinely new idea!" posted under an answer: check out for instance the accepted answer of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253059

Comment: I don’t think you should trust a published paper without personally understanding it, much less a short post on a website.  Adding a thin veneer of “peer review” to MO would be bad in the sense that it would encourage people to be overly trusting of it.  If you need something here for a paper or something, do your due diligence!

Comment: @AndyPutman Perhaps you verify all the main proofs in the area you are working on, but in other areas one sometimes reads a survey of results (with some illustrative proofs) that were verified by others.